# Is there a faster approach to change a data type on a feature class field in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5?

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, sql-server, performance

I've followed the "Calculate Field Tool" steps from this article https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000023089 to change the data type on a field but it takes so long to copy the field value from the old field to the new one. I'm just looking for other/faster options (if any) without losing the data.

The datatype is currently long and I'll change it to text(64). I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5 and the database is SQL Server.

Comment: I'd copy feature class to memory workspace, alter field or use field calculator, overwrite original. It pays even for time wasted on copying.

Comment: The best practice here isn't the fastest way, it's the way that preserves data integrity with the highest reliability (as is often the case with databases) -- Create a new table in the database, and insert from the previous one. If the table is versioned, you need to post all the edits and remove versioning before making the change.